# The right method of sharing database variables (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, database, declaration, fxcop, code-sharing

I have been sharing database variables using the following code:

```
Namespace DataAccessVariables
    Public Class Vars
        Public Shared s As String
        Public Shared con As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Dev").ToString()
        Public Shared c As New SqlConnection(con)
        Public Shared x As New SqlCommand(s, c)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I then import this to my project like this:

```
Imports DataAccessVariables.Vars
```

When I check the site with FXCop, I get this message:

```
Error, Certainty 90, for StaticHolderTypesShouldNotHaveConstructors
{
    Target       : DBVars  (IntrospectionTargetType)
    Resolution   : "Remove the public constructors from 'Vars'."
    Help         : http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library/ms182169(VS.90).aspx  (String)
    Category     : Microsoft.Design  (String)
    CheckId      : CA1053  (String)
    RuleFile     : Design Rules  (String)
    Info         : "Instances of types that define only static members 
                   do not need to be created. Many compilers will automatically 
                   add a public default constructor if no constructor 
                   is specified. To prevent this, adding an empty private 
                   constructor may be required."
    Created      : 2010/04/20 01:25:16 PM  (DateTime)
    LastSeen     : 2010/04/21 07:17:46 AM  (DateTime)
    Status       : Active  (MessageStatus)
    Fix Category : Breaking  (FixCategories)
}
```

If I remove the 'Public Shared' from the declarations, then the variables are not picked up in my pages. Can anyone show me the correct way of sharing them?

Thanks a lot,
Phil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error isn't telling you to remove the Public Shared variables. Instead it's letting you know that it is possible to create a new instance of your `Vars` class, even though it includes only `Shared` members. To resolve the issue, define a private constructor:

```
Private Sub New()
End Sub
```

This will prevent any code creating an instance of the `Vars` class outside of the class itself.

Answer (score 4):

Is that the *only* code in your class?

Also, you should not create a global (static) `SqlConnection`. Simply create the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects on-demand. Connection pooling will ensure that only one physical database connection is made at a time.

The way you've got it here, it's not thread-safe (if two people make a request at the same time, for example, things are going to get *really* screwy).